# Redolog management in Oraclce DBA

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am confused about `group#` in `v$logfile`(Redolog management in Oracle). What exactly is `group#`? If `group#` is a datafile if there are 13 tablespaces in one database can we create 13 `group#` with its 13 respective members?

Comment: ["Redo log group identifier number"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/dynviews_2033.htm#REFRN30129); this has nothing to do with tablespace data files. Have you looked at the docs, e.g. [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/physical.htm#CNCPT11302) and in more detail [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/onlineredo.htm#ADMIN11308)?

Answer (score 1):

Redo logs have nothing to do with tablespaces or how many tablespaces you have.  Committed transactions are written into your redo logs and your SCN is updated. Make sure you multiplex members, because if you lose one member, your database can be restored and restarted with the other member.  In a production database you should have at least 3 groups.  We have up to 6 groups.

One group should have a CURRENT status and the other groups can be a combination of ACTIVE/INACTIVE (usually) based on how quickly they are being archived.

Verbose description of status:

UNUSED - Online redo log has never been written to. This is the state of a redo log that was just added, or just after a RESETLOGS, when it is not the current redo log.

CURRENT - Current redo log. This implies that the redo log is active. The redo log could be open or closed.

ACTIVE - Log is active but is not the current log. It is needed for crash recovery. It may be in use for block recovery. It may or may not be archived.

CLEARING - Log is being re-created as an empty log after an ALTER DATABASE CLEAR LOGFILE statement. After the log is cleared, the status changes to UNUSED.

CLEARING_CURRENT - Current log is being cleared of a closed thread. The log can stay in this status if there is some failure in the switch such as an I/O error writing the new log header.

INACTIVE - Log is no longer needed for instance recovery. It may be in use for media recovery. It may or may not be archived.

Use this script for more information:

```
select a.group#, a.status, b.member 
from
v$log a, v$logfile b
where a.group#=b.group#;
```